# Redirect loop between co.uk site to .com (wordpress)

Tags: php, wordpress, redirect, lamp

I have a website that is being redirected from a .co.uk site to a .com site and from a .com back to the .co.uk site causing a redirect loop (ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS shows up).

The strange thing is that this site was working fine for months when this issue just popped up out of no where.  When I did a "git status" to see which files have been changed there where 1000s of files deleted and modified.  Here is a screen shot showing some of these files updated[image] (I most certainly didn't update them)

Any idea what might have caused this issue?  Here is what the .htaccess file looks like:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

Comment: from the description of your question, I can guess that the issue might reside in your redirection that you are redirecting site your site from `.com` to `.co.uk` and again redirect it from `.co.uk` to `.com`

Comment: can you share the `.htaccess` file and what is the site_url in your database?

Comment: @DhavalPurohit I've updated the question to show those details.

Comment: There is no issue with your `.htaccess` file.

Comment: can you able to share your site URL so I can check where it is redirecting. @John

Comment: so you have the IIS server than kindly share your web.config file 
`.htaccess` won't work with IIS Server

Comment: your domain currently points to a hosting of an IIS server, not the apache

Comment: check with this `http://www.redirect-checker.org`

Comment: @DhavalPurohit thanks for  spotting that! It appears that my client put a 301 on his GoDaddy account for one site to point to the co.uk site and the .co.uk site to point to the .com site... even though he "swore" he didn't change anything on that panel. haha.

Comment: you are welcome @John

Answer (score -1):

If you have backup of old version then just upload again old files which updated on site.

but these are just pdf files updates I don't think they are causing problem.